# How do I fit a damped sine wave to data

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting, analysis

For my experimental project I have fit a damped sine wave onto data I acquired for the amplitude of vibration. I am trying to analyse the data in python but don't even know where to start when trying to model it as a damped wave. So any tips or help on how to get started would be much appreciated.

The Amplitude data is as follows:

```
A = [174, 174, 173, 173, 173, 173, 174, 175, 179, 182, 179, 175, 172, 178,
     181, 176, 179, 172, 171, 177, 179, 181, 176, 167, 174]
```

and the time data is just a constant time apart so something like this

```
t = np.array([0., 0.04, 0.08, 0.12, 0.16, 0.2, 0.24, 0.28, 0.32, 0.36, 0.4,
              0.44, 0.48, 0.52, 0.56, 0.6, 0.64, 0.68, 0.72, 0.76, 0.8, 0.84,
              0.88, 0.92, 0.96])
```

The fitted model will be something like this:

y(t) = A * exp(-lambda * t) * cos(omega * t + phi)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think you'd need a +C constant in your equation for it to match your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but nothing more than a comment. I cannot edit it in the comments section because a picture is absolutely essential and one cannot put a picture in comments.

If I made no mistake the graphical representation of the data is :

[image]

This graph doesn't look like a damped sinusodal function. I wonder if one is able to say what kind of function it is. It looks more like an highly scattered linear function.

Can you roughly sketch (without calculus) the curve that you expect ?

Comment: Oof. Maybe the data is backwards? If you flip it horizontally it looks more like it's being damped.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first, I'd find the approximate locations where the nodes are, i.e., where the curve equals the average value of all the data, and then find the frequency from there. Then I'd record the amplitudes of the first few peaks to get the initial amplitude, and also the ratio between adjacent peak amplitudes, which'll get you the lambda in your equation. The time of the first peak will also get you your phase angle, phi.

Comment: Is there anyway to automate this more, so that the ration between the peak amplitudes is recorded. As I have to do this with a lot of data sets possibly upwards of 50, and that may be quite time consuming.

Comment: @HarrySpratt Well yes, I meant to do this in Python.